# Не могу понять ,как создать пустой список указателей на объект через std :: vector

Tags: c++, классы

Создать пустой список указателей на объекты класса Круг, используя коллекции языка С++ (например, `std::vector<T>`).

Comment: class Circle { ... };
    std::vector<Circle*> empyt_list;

Comment: @KoVadim Это пустой вектор :) Пустой список - `std::list<Circle*> empty_list;`

Comment: я думаю, что правильный ответ на вопрос автора вопроса будет звучать так  `std::vector<std::list<Circle*> >`.

Comment: Действительно, путаница какая-то вышла. Может автор вопроса как-то прокомментирует высказанные решения?